# How do I run Python using HTML?

Tags: python, html, batch-file

I'm trying to get my html file to execute python source code using python-multitouch batch file.

The file name is

```
C:\Users\Alien\Desktop\PYMT\pymt.bat
```

and I'm running from

```
C:\Users\Alien\Desktop\Multitouch\website template\home.html
```

How can I do this?

Comment: With this much information, body can help you. You have to be more specific: What do you want, what in those files, what are your input, what is your expected output...

Comment: HTML files generally don't execute or contain Python.  You need to provide more information for anyone to make sense of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one simple thing...
Write code in javascript with Ajax to call a function in your python file from document.ready() function.

e.g.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax
            ({  
                type: "GET",
                    url: "/topythonFunction/", 
                data: { },
                success: function (data) 
                {   
    }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible by just doing something like this..

```
<a href="../../PYMT/pymt.bat">RUN PYTHON</a>
```

Evert